# How to setup GLUT lib into Clion

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, clion

I have downloaded the glut3.7 lib. I would like to use it on my OpenGL project.
I have included the header file as follow:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

If I run the following code I will get the following error:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
}
```

Error:

```
CMakeFiles\playground.dir/objects.a(playground.cpp.obj): In function `main':
.../OpenGl/OpenGL-
Template/playground/playground.cpp:23: undefined reference to `glutInit@8'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\playground.dir\build.make:126: 
playground.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:68: 
CMakeFiles/playground.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:80: 
CMakeFiles/playground.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:163: playground] Error 2
```

I have included the directory, in which my glut is located: (CMakeLists.txt)

```
include_directories(
glfw-3.1.2/include/GLFW/
glew-1.13.0/include/
glut37/glut-3.7/include/
)
```

All other libs (e.g. glwf, glew, glm) are working....

EDIT: I heard this could be a linker problem. If so, how do i link this lib?

Comment: "I have downloaded the glut3.7 lib" [whyyyyyyyy](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: OK, Im trying this with freeglut3.0  now, but I have still the same issue as before....

Answer (score 0):

You will need -lglut as part of your link command, you may also need to add a library search directory with the -L flag (as in -L).